# How to add padding to Krypton Button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, krypton-toolkit, krypton

I added a krypton button to a form, on the commonstate i added and image also set aligne to left-center before the text.

But i cannot finding padding option to push the image away from the left edge of the button.

Please, is there away i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to add padding specifically to an image thorugh a property like `Padding` or `ImagePadding`.

If you want to, you can try overriding the button's `OnPaint` method and manually draw the image and text with your spacing.

Basic Example:

```cs
public class MyCustomKryptonButton : KryptonButton
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pevent);
        
        int imgPaddingLeft = 10;
        int imgPaddingTop = 10;
        
        if (this.Values.Image != null)
        {
            pevent.Graphics.DrawImage(this.Values.Image, new Point(imgPaddingLeft, imgPaddingTop));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!
I was able to fix it by changing the buttonstlye to ButtonSpec